# Document invalid/ exists error

Tags: 2013, document-library, folder

I am getting a weird error when I am trying to upload a file in my document library. It says that the file is invalid. Exact error message:

> The URL '/.doc' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web.

So I uploaded a file with a different name and tried changing the name, it then gave me file exists error. But there is no file with the name I am trying to upload.

Comment: What filename are you trying to use? It may be using reserved characters or wordings

Comment: Sec2-3.doc, we also have similar file names like Sec1-2.doc etc that were uploaded without any error

Comment: OK, so not reserved characters. Are you absolutely sure there exists no documents with that name? It may be a document uploaded by another user, but that has never been checked in so it is not visible to you

Comment: I had logged in using System Account configured to view all documents. So if there was a file it would have been visible. I was wondering is this got to do anything with the SQL side?

Comment: Check here http://www.guidemethrough.com/home/sharepoint-manage-files-that-have-no-checked-in-version/

Comment: Checked this as well, there are no files. However I am seeing a DB entry in 'DocStreams' and 'DocTable' for the file name that throws error. Took the name from 'DocTable'. Has a previous file delete gone wrong?